Element of orthogonal group with determinant -1
Let $S$ denote a symmetric even positive definite matrix. We consider the integral orthogonal group of $S$, which is denoted by $O(S):= \{g\in GL_{n}(\mathbb{Z}): g^{t}Sg=S\}$.
Is it always true that $O(S)$ contains an element with determinant $-1$?
This is definitely true when $n$ is odd (by just taking $-1_n$) but I cannot show it when $n$ is even.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What does "even matrix" mean? It contains even integer values?

It means $x^tSx$ is even for any integer vector x.
